# Открыть Layout

Tags: xml, java, android

Как в приложении андроид сделать так, чтобы по клику открывался ниже доп. layout (типа спойлера, что ли), можно было также скрыть опять по клику? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @DenShDen, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863409/android-views-expand-animation

Answer (score 1):

Делайте разметку, у того layout, который нужно показать, указываете свойство `visibility = invisible`. В коде подкючаете layout и вешаете onClick на ту штуку, которая должна отрывать layout. В onClick пишите что-то вроде

```
myHideLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible); если надо показать
myHideLayout.setVisibility(View.Invisible); если надо скрыть
```

Comment: оо, спасибо, сейчас попробую..))

Answer (score 1):

```
myLayout.setVisiblity(View.Gone); //лэйаут вообще исчезает - не занимает места
myLayout.setVisiblity(View.Invisible);// Лэйаута не видно, но место он занимает
myLayout.setVisiblity(View.Visible);// А вот и лэйаут!
```